# php setcookie isn't setting the cookie

Tags: php, cookies

I have an application that uses saml authentication and passes the response back via a cookie to the return URL the SP provides. The php code looks like this

```
setcookie('auth', $cred, time() + 30, parse_url($location, PHP_URL_HOST));
error_log($_COOKIE['auth']);

header('Location: ' . $location, true, 303);
die();
```

The redirect works fine but the cookie is not set. This is confirmed both in php as shown above, and in my application using `document.cookies`

I've exported the HAR to view the request and it actually looks like the cookie is being set, but it's still not accessible via document.cookie. The way it is supposed to work is that the application changes the window.location to the php file that authenticates, sets the cookie and redirects to the return parameter. Judging by the fact that the request is sent with the cookie, I'd guess that it is being set, but I can't seem to access it.

```
  {
    "startedDateTime": "2017-10-27T18:05:36.538Z",
    "time": 271.7059999888301,
    "request": {
      "method": "GET",
      "url": "https://supportworkslab.sw.test/sw/selfservice/sso/saml_auth.php?wssinstance=selfservice&returnto=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsw%2Fselfservice",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Encoding",
          "value": "gzip, deflate, br"
        },
        {
          "name": "Host",
          "value": "supportworkslab.sw.test"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept-Language",
          "value": "en-US,en;q=0.9"
        },
        {
          "name": "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests",
          "value": "1"
        },
        {
          "name": "User-Agent",
          "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.2; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/62.0.3202.62 Safari/537.36"
        },
        {
          "name": "Accept",
          "value": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8"
        },
        {
          "name": "Referer",
          "value": "http://localhost/sw/selfservice/"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cookie",
          "value": "auth=eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24gc3VjY2VzcyEiLCJjdXN0aWQiOiJhbGFuYyIsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6IjU5ZjM2MGRjLTBhOTI5NWFlLTQxYzEiLCJ3ZWJGbGFncyI6IjIxNDc0ODk1NTEiLCJjYWxsQ2xhc3MiOiJJbmNpZGVudCIsImFzc2lnbkdyb3VwIjoiU1VQUE9SVCIsImFzc2lnbkFuYWx5c3QiOiIifQ%3D%3D; SimpleSAMLAuthToken=_04a2be772f96fad7c5e2452846c05df5cbd570305e; SimpleSAML=62d6b2ebea7f66b0360a328dcb4f77a7; PHPSESSID=k9hpb09i3omt43bv7gireeuid0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Connection",
          "value": "keep-alive"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-cache"
        }
      ],
      "queryString": [
        {
          "name": "wssinstance",
          "value": "selfservice"
        },
        {
          "name": "returnto",
          "value": "http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fsw%2Fselfservice"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [
        {
          "name": "auth",
          "value": "eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24gc3VjY2VzcyEiLCJjdXN0aWQiOiJhbGFuYyIsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6IjU5ZjM2MGRjLTBhOTI5NWFlLTQxYzEiLCJ3ZWJGbGFncyI6IjIxNDc0ODk1NTEiLCJjYWxsQ2xhc3MiOiJJbmNpZGVudCIsImFzc2lnbkdyb3VwIjoiU1VQUE9SVCIsImFzc2lnbkFuYWx5c3QiOiIifQ%3D%3D",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": false,
          "secure": false
        },
        {
          "name": "SimpleSAMLAuthToken",
          "value": "_04a2be772f96fad7c5e2452846c05df5cbd570305e",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": false,
          "secure": false
        },
        {
          "name": "SimpleSAML",
          "value": "62d6b2ebea7f66b0360a328dcb4f77a7",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": false,
          "secure": false
        },
        {
          "name": "PHPSESSID",
          "value": "k9hpb09i3omt43bv7gireeuid0",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": false,
          "secure": false
        }
      ],
      "headersSize": 996,
      "bodySize": 0
    },
    "response": {
      "status": 303,
      "statusText": "See Other",
      "httpVersion": "HTTP/1.1",
      "headers": [
        {
          "name": "Pragma",
          "value": "no-cache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Date",
          "value": "Fri, 27 Oct 2017 18:05:36 GMT"
        },
        {
          "name": "Server",
          "value": "Apache"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Type",
          "value": "text/html"
        },
        {
          "name": "Location",
          "value": "http://localhost/sw/selfservice"
        },
        {
          "name": "Set-Cookie",
          "value": "SimpleSAML=62d6b2ebea7f66b0360a328dcb4f77a7; path=/; HttpOnly"
        },
        {
          "name": "Set-Cookie",
          "value": "PHPSESSID=k9hpb09i3omt43bv7gireeuid0; path=/; HttpOnly"
        },
        {
          "name": "Set-Cookie",
          "value": "auth=eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24gc3VjY2VzcyEiLCJjdXN0aWQiOiJhbGFuYyIsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6IjU5ZjM3NTcwLTBhZTJmNzAzLTNmMTIiLCJ3ZWJGbGFncyI6IjIxNDc0ODk1NTEiLCJjYWxsQ2xhc3MiOiJJbmNpZGVudCIsImFzc2lnbkdyb3VwIjoiU1VQUE9SVCIsImFzc2lnbkFuYWx5c3QiOiIifQ%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 27-Oct-2017 18:06:36 GMT; Max-Age=60; domain=localhost"
        },
        {
          "name": "Cache-Control",
          "value": "no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Security-Policy",
          "value": "default-src 'self' *.sw.test; frame-src *.twitter.com; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' *.twitter.com *.twimg.com; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'  *.twitter.com *.twimg.com; img-src 'self' data: *.twimg.com *.twitter.com;"
        },
        {
          "name": "Connection",
          "value": "Keep-Alive"
        },
        {
          "name": "Keep-Alive",
          "value": "timeout=5, max=100"
        },
        {
          "name": "Content-Length",
          "value": "0"
        },
        {
          "name": "Expires",
          "value": "Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT"
        }
      ],
      "cookies": [
        {
          "name": "SimpleSAML",
          "value": "62d6b2ebea7f66b0360a328dcb4f77a7",
          "path": "/",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": true,
          "secure": false
        },
        {
          "name": "PHPSESSID",
          "value": "k9hpb09i3omt43bv7gireeuid0",
          "path": "/",
          "expires": null,
          "httpOnly": true,
          "secure": false
        },
        {
          "name": "auth",
          "value": "eyJzdWNjZXNzIjoiQXV0aGVudGljYXRpb24gc3VjY2VzcyEiLCJjdXN0aWQiOiJhbGFuYyIsInNlc3Npb25JZCI6IjU5ZjM3NTcwLTBhZTJmNzAzLTNmMTIiLCJ3ZWJGbGFncyI6IjIxNDc0ODk1NTEiLCJjYWxsQ2xhc3MiOiJJbmNpZGVudCIsImFzc2lnbkdyb3VwIjoiU1VQUE9SVCIsImFzc2lnbkFuYWx5c3QiOiIifQ%3D%3D",
          "domain": "localhost",
          "expires": "2017-10-27T18:06:36.254Z",
          "httpOnly": false,
          "secure": false
        }
      ],
      "content": {
        "size": 0,
        "mimeType": "text/html",
        "compression": 0
      },
      "redirectURL": "http://localhost/sw/selfservice",
      "headersSize": 1104,
      "bodySize": 0,
      "_transferSize": 1104
    },
```

Comment: reload that page, you'll see that the cookie just might get set after all and check to see if it is set.

Comment: `$_COOKIE` shows the **incoming** cookies. To diagnose the issue you should use you browser developer tools.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I've been doing that there is no cookie set even though the response does have the proper set-cookie header

Comment: Show the response headers (`wget -S`) in your question; elaborate on domain name etc.

Comment: I can see `Set-Cookie: auth=eyJ...%3D%3D; expires=Fri, 27-Oct-2017 18:06:36 GMT; Max-Age=60; domain=localhost`. Please check the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your $cred var is defined and a valid string

Make sure the result of the parse_url() function on $location returns a valid string....it has to match exactly the domain you work on so watch out for subdomain issues.

Obviously make sure you check before it expires....60 seconds.

Comment: Yes I realize that I didn't give it much time, but that should be more than enough for the application to check if we authenticated.